# How can I load Google Tag Manager to a next.js app, AFTER the app is fully loaded?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, google-tag-manager, dynamic-import

I'm building a next.js application and would like to load Google Tag Manager (GTM) only AFTER the entire page is loaded. The goal behind this is to improve the website performance.

**Has anyone figured out a way how I can run third-party JS code (like GTM) only after the application has fully loaded?**

I'm currently adding using the 'conventional' way to inject GTM to my next.js app ([source](https://www.learnbestcoding.com/post/9/easiest-way-to-integrate-google-analytics-with-react-js-and-next-js)) by adding the `<script>` tag into the `<Head>` and the `<noscript>` tag into the `<body>` tag in the `_document.js` file:

```
<Head>
      {/* Google Tag Manager */}
      <script
        dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
          __html: `(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
                new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
                j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
                'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
                })(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-XXXXXXX');`
        }}
      />
          {/* End Google Tag Manager */}
...
...
</Head>

<body style={{ backgroundColor: theme.palette.primary.background }}>
       {/* Google Tag Manager (noscript) */}
       <noscript
          dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
            __html: '<iframe src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-XXXXXXX" height="0" width="0" style="display:none;visibility:hidden"></iframe>'
          }}
      />
      {/* End Google Tag Manager (noscript) */}
```

Comment: I think it might be easier to just use an NPM package for this, for example: https://github.com/XD2Sketch/next-google-tag-manager

Answer (score 4):

How are you measuring performance?

Straight from the Next.js docs: https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/script#afterinteractive, you want to do this:

```
<Script
  strategy="afterInteractive"
  id="your-id"
  dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
    __html: `
    (function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
    new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
    j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
    'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
    })(window,document,'script','dataLayer', 'GTM-XXXXXX');
  `,
  }}
/>
```

`afterInteractive` simply puts the script before the closing body tag, so it loads after the page is *interactive*.

You might be better off placing the `<noscript>` tag in `_document.tsx`, it's tidier.

I've written a fairly in-depth article on how to do this: https://morganfeeney.com/how-to/integrate-google-tag-manager-with-next-js

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code example below to achieve lazy loading for Google Tag Manager scripts.

You can use the built-in Script component provided by Next Js.

```
import Script from "next/script";

<Script strategy="lazyOnload" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: `(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
            new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
            j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
            'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
            })(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-XXXXXXX');`, }} />
```

Comment: I tried doing so already but when debugging that setup on the Google's Tag Assistant I find out the the GTM tag is not set up correctly. Did your proposed solution work for you?

Comment: Yes it should work correctly if you placed the scripts in the ```_document.js``` on the Head. You can also search for Next Js Official examples from their GitHub.

Answer (score 0):

Although not a trivial topic, you can try the Effect Hook which can run some additional code after React has updated the DOM. https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html